# Can a deploy with multiple ReplicaSets run CMD different command?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I want to create few pods from same image (I have the Dockerfile) so i want to use ReplicaSets.
but the final CMD command need to be different for each container.

for exmple
(https://www.devspace.sh/docs/5.x/configuration/images/entrypoint-cmd):

```yaml
image:
  frontend:
    image: john/appfrontend
    cmd:
    - run
    - dev
```

And the other container will do:

```yaml
image:
  frontend:
    image: john/appfrontend
    cmd:
    - run
    - <new value>
```

Also I would like to move the CMD value from a list, so i would like the value there to be variable (it will be in a loop so each Pod will have to be created separately).

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly do this as you've described it.  A ReplicaSet manages some number of *identical* Pods, where the command, environment variables, and every other detail except for the Pod name are the same across every replica.

In practice you don't usually directly use ReplicaSets; instead, you create a Deployment, which creates one or more ReplicaSets, which create Pods.  The same statement and mechanics apply to Deployments, though.

Since this is specifically in the context of a Helm chart, you can have two separate Deployment YAML files in your chart, but then use Helm templating to reduce the amount of code that needs to be repeated.  You can add a helper template to `templates/_helpers.tpl` that contains most of the data for a container

```yaml
# templates/_helpers.tpl
{{- define "myapp.container" -}}
image: my-image:{{ .Values.tag }}
env:
  - name: FOO
    value: bar
  - name: ET
    value: cetera
{{ end -}}
```

Now you can have two template Deployment files, but provide a separate `command:` for each.

```yaml
# templates/deployment-one.yml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "myapp.name" . }}-one
  labels:
{{ include "myapp.labels" . | indent 4 }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.one.replicas }}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
{{ include "myapp.labels" . | indent 8 }}
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: frontend
{{ include "myapp.container" . | indent 10 }}
          command:
            - npm
            - run
            - dev
```

There is still a fair amount to copy and paste, but you should be able to `cp` the whole file.  Most of the boilerplate is Kubernetes boilerplate and every Deployment will have these parts; little of it is specific to any given application.

If your image has a default `CMD` (this is good practice) then you can omit the `command:` override on one of the Deployments, and it will run that default `CMD`.

In the question you make specific reference to Dockerfile `CMD`.  One important terminology difference is that Kubernetes `command:` overrides Docker `ENTRYPOINT`, and Kubernetes `args:` matches `CMD`.  If you are using an entrypoint wrapper script, in this example you will need to provide `args:` instead of `command:` so that the wrapper is still invoked.